# Sliding navigation not visible if I scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I used jquery to keep the top navigation visible when the user scrolls down the website. If the user scrolls down the page the jquery code for the sliding nav still works, but the div for the sliding nav is not visible.

HTML code

```
    <div id="headerwrapper">
        <header>
            <img id="logo" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.png" alt="Unified Software Solutions">

            <img id="navigation" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/nav.png" alt="Navigation">

            <div id="navigation_menu">
                <ul id="menu-navigation>
                <!-- nav items -->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
```

CSS Code

```
*{
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#headerwrapper{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
    height: auto !important;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #ccc;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
    height: auto !important;
}

#logo{
    position: relative;
    top: 12px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 80%;
}

#navigation{
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    right: 5px;
    width: 25px;
    max-width: 25px;
    margin: 8px;
    float: right;
}

#navigation_menu{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: -400px;
    width: 400px;
    min-height: 100px;
    height: auto !important;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #ccc;
    z-index: 1;
}

#content{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 60px;
    height: auto !important;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Scroll JQuery Code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 40){
            $("#headerwrapper").css("position", "fixed");
        }

        if($(window).scrollTop() < 40){
            $("#headerwrapper").css("position", "relative");
        }
    });

});
```

Sliding Nav JQuery Code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var slid = false;
    var right = $("#navigation_menu").css("right");

    $("#navigation").click(function(){
        if(!slid && right == "-400px"){
            $("#navigation_menu").animate({right: '0px'});
            slid = true;
            return;
        }
        else{
            $("#navigation_menu").animate({right: '-400px'});
            slid = false;
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

The sliding nav code works until the page is scrolled on. Then it still scrolls but there seems to be an issue with the z-index. At least that is what I can infer from the Chrome developer console. The div slide but is underneath everything. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to show more HTML (not only header).

Comment: The content div is litterally everything between the header and footer. I figure since the div shows under the content div that would suffice. The css is everything that has to do with what i have done so far.

Comment: So it is working good - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOJBYQ

Comment: No it is not. Like i stated multiple times when I scroll down the sliding nav does not work. It is even apparent in your link.

Comment: Ok, I see the problem now.

Comment: It works with `position: fixed` (on #navigation_menu) but I don;t know if you are good with that.

Comment: That is odd. It was only not working on the Chrome inpector when using the mobile phone feature. It works if im in the normal browser mode though. Thank you for the help.